# css responsive background gets zoomed when more content appear

Tags: html, css, responsive

I use such css for setting responsive background. When I see it on mobile, the background is zoomed in more and more if there is a lot of content appears on page. What is the proper way to avoid zooming of background? thanx

```
body {
    background: url('someimage.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;

    background-size: cover;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A viewport meta tag like this might help (at the top of your html):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This will ensure that on a mobile screen, the content will not be displayed as on a large screen, and the width of the body element will only be as wide as the screen.

Comment: I have it, does not help

Answer (score 0):

Its due to cover, cover will make sure the whole container gets covered with the image. You could try to use contain

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define the body height as 100%, this should avoid vertical stretching of the background image:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: url('someimage.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And for that body height to work , you should also add this to your CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

With these setting, the `body`s `overflow` is the default `auto`, which will cause a scroll bar to appear as soon as the contents exceed the 100% height.